# Become a full adminitstrator in Win 10

Tags: windows-10

The official MS doc says:

> In Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016, Windows setup disables the
>   built-in Administrator account and creates another local account that
>   is a member of the Administrators group.

My question: is there a way to make that default (created on win install) user account full admin account, that is to have absolutely the same power & privileges as build in, hidden by default `Administrator` (named) account? I'm asking that because even if the account belongs to the `Administrators` group i still don't have a full control. For example i can't edit files in "Program Files" folder or get prompts for elevating admin privileges doing some tasks.

Comment: Adding a user to the Administrator group gives that user all the permissions of an Administrator.  There is no different between a user that was placed in the Administrator user group and the built-in Administrator user in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

If you open an elevated (admin rights) command line and paste the following command, you'll enable the built-in Administrator account on your PC:

net user administrator /active:yes

Note that depending on what language your PC is, you may have to change the word "administrator". You can use a capital first letter too.